# Problems finding the Eigenstates of a Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I am solving the problem 5.6 from Zettili Quantum Mechanics book:

I have an Hamiltonian given by $\hat{H} = \epsilon \hat{\sigma} \cdot \hat{n}$ where $\hat{\sigma}$ represents the Pauli Matrices and $\hat{n}$ a arbitrary unit vector.

Using spherical coordinates I found the Eigenvalues, which are $E_{1} = \epsilon$ and $E_2 = -\epsilon$ but I can't find the Eigenvectors correctly. I find the following equation for the Eigenvectors equation:

$$ x \cos\theta + ye^{-i\phi} \sin\theta = E x$$
$$ x \sin{\theta}e^{i\phi} - y \cos\theta = E y$$

Where $E$ stands for the Eigenvalues in each case. For the first Eigenvalue I get the following relation between the x and y:

$$ \frac{x}{y} = \frac{e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta}$$ and from this point on I don't understand how the author proceeds with the solution. He writes that the previous relation is equal to this one:

$$\frac{x}{y} =\frac{\cos\frac{\theta}{2} e^{-i\phi/2}}{\sin\frac{\theta}{2} e^{i\phi/2} }$$

And that the numerator is the first element of the eigenvalue and the denominator is the second element of the eigenvector. But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your eigenvector equation we have:
$$\frac{x}{y} = e^{-i\phi}\frac{ \sin \theta}{1-\cos\theta}=e^{-i\phi}\frac{2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)}{2\cos^2(\theta/2)}=\frac{\sin(\theta/2)e^{-i\phi/2}}{\cos(\theta/2)e^{i\phi/2}}$$
Where I've used the [double angle formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae). 
For your second question, keep in mind that for an eigenvalue-eigenvector pair $E,|v\rangle$, we have by definition:
$$\hat H|v \rangle = E|v \rangle$$
Multiplying both sides by some constant $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ gives:
$$\hat H(\alpha|v \rangle) = E(\alpha|v \rangle)$$
which means that $|v' \rangle = \alpha|v \rangle$ is also an eigenvector of $\hat H$ with the same eigenvalue. This means that you always have the freedom of multiplying the eigenvector by a constant when your calculating it, without worrying about it not being an eigenvector anymore. Another way you can look at this is that because of this freedom, *any vector with components satisfying* $x/y = {\sin(\theta/2)e^{-i\phi/2}}/{\cos(\theta/2)e^{i\phi/2}}$ *is a valid eigenvector*. 
In conclusion, the eigenvector with components $x={\sin(\theta/2)e^{-i\phi/2}}$ and $y={\cos(\theta/2)e^{i\phi/2}}$ is one valid eigenvector, since it gives the right $x/y$ ratio. Another (completely valid) choice would be something like $x={\sin(\theta/2)e^{-i\phi/2}}/{\cos(\theta/2)e^{i\phi/2}}$ and $y=1$. 
However, in Quantum Mechanics, people conventionally prefer to choose the normalized eigenstate (such that $\Vert v \Vert = 1$) between this infinite set of choices of eigenvectors; as this usually makes calculations (of probabilities, etc.) much simpler. Because of this, the author's choice is preferred by convention because $\Vert v \Vert^2 =|x|^2+|y|^2=\sin^2(\theta/2)+\cos^2(\theta/2)=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Your explanation was very instructive. I was with the same kind of problem in another question and I think you may have answered it as well.

Comment: You're more than welcome.

Comment: I just have one more question. When I get equations that lead to no information about the elements of the eigenvector I suppose we can set any value for the same reason as you have exposed?

Comment: Even though doing that is not wrong, I would try to get in the habit of sticking to the convention $\Vert v \Vert = 1$, since it will make your life easier in future courses. You can systematically find the eigenvector with this condition by writing $|x|^2+|y|^2=1$, which gives $|y|^2(1+|x/y|^2)=1$. Since you already know $x/y$, you can simply solve for $y$, and then get $x$ from the known $x/y$ value.